# Gerando DOC a partir de conteúdo HTML

Tags: php, download, microsoft-word

Estou usando o plugin [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) para converter textos HTML em um arquivo .docx

Mas quando eu vou fazer o download do arquivo gerado, recebo só com caracteres muito doidos como:

> PK########�^uK�j�#c###!#######[Content_Types].xml���N�0#E�|E�-Jܲ@#5��#*Q>5'��_�8}�=��D#AC�v#)��s�G�G��5�
>   "j�J6,#,#'��nQ���s~�2L�)a���m#�d|5�m#F�#K�L)�s�r    V�#8�T>Z��5.x#�C,��

Já procurei aqui no stackoverflow, no próprio github do projeto e no google em geral, mas não consegui solucionar o problema.

Meu código vai a seguir:

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);
@ini_set ('display_errors', 'on');
require_once '../../../../vendor/autoload.php';

$my_content = $_POST['html_content'];

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $my_content);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachement;filename="teste.docx"');
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
?>
```

Comment: Verifique os encodes na geração do arquivo, adicione o header pro formato correto. Um exemplo seria adicionar `header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar @MarcelodeAndrade. Eu tentei dessa forma e diversas outras no header, nada resolvia. Resolvi então salvar o arquivo numa pasta temporária e depois realizar o download. Funcionou, assim que estiver 100% pronto eu vou postar a solução aqui.